# org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns in ENUM entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I created database, which have a references with ENUM table and I have exception in entity of this enum.

scripts example:

```
CREATE TABLE status (
  code VARCHAR(40),
  status ENUM('not started', 'in progress', 'finished')
);

insert into status (code, status)
values (1, 'not started'),
       (2, 'in progress'),
       (3, 'finished');
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `explorer` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `query` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (status_id) REFERENCES status(code)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

---

So, after creating table I did create automatically entities for this tables:

- Explorer:

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "explorer", schema = "parsebeandeveloper", catalog = "")
  public class ExplorerEntity {
  private long id;
  private Timestamp createDate;
  private String query;
  private String title;
  private Integer statusId;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  public long getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "create_date")
  public Timestamp getCreateDate() {
      return createDate;
  }

  public void setCreateDate(Timestamp createDate) {
      this.createDate = createDate;
  }

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "query")
  public String getQuery() {
      return query;
  }

  public void setQuery(String query) {
      this.query = query;
  }

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "title")
  public String getTitle() {
      return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
  }

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "status_id")
  public Integer getStatusId() {
      return statusId;
  }

  public void setStatusId(Integer statusId) {
      this.statusId = statusId;
  }
  }
  ```

class, where I get exception:

- Status:

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "status", schema = "parsebeandeveloper")
  public class StatusEntity {
  private Integer code;
  private Object status;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "code")
  public Integer getCode() {
      return code;
  }

  public void setCode(Integer code) {
      this.code = code;
  }

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "status")
  public Object getStatus() {
      return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(Object status) {
      this.status = status;
  }
  ```

  }

That, what I get in console:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>
> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path 
>   resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa
>   /HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested > exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: 
>   default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is 
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: **property mapping has wrong number of 
>   columns: com.sb.bean.parser.explorer.model.domain2.StatusEntity.status type: > object**

I have think, that I did make mistake

- in the creating table `explorer`, in string:

  ```
    FOREIGN KEY (status_id) REFERENCES status(code)
  ```
- or in creating class `EntityStatus`

**How to correctly create `Status` entity or create references between tables in this case?**

Comment: Change `code` and `status` fields of `StatusEntity` to `String` type and see if it works.

Comment: @tsolakp I just changed `status` type to String, and all works. Thanks

Comment: @tsolakp if you answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hibernate complains that it is not able to map `StatusEntity.status` because it is declared `Object` type.

You can change it to `String` type which Hibernate should be able to map to database ENUM type.

You can also use Java enum for `status` field and have hibernate map it using `@Enumerated` annotation.

Comment: So basically we can't have an object that includes a sub-object / object from another table?